# struts.convention.result.path is not working in Struts2

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, action, struts2-convention-plugin

My current project structure is as follows

```
WebContent
   WEB-INF
   View
     TestPage.jsp
     other JSP pages...
```

My assignment is to put all JSP pages inside folder WEB-INF and do all relative changes in the project.

```
WebContent
   WEB-INF
      View
        TestPage.jsp
        other JSP pages...
```

So I have to update all result tag in struts.xml

```
<result name="success">/View/TestPage.jsp</result>
```

to

```
<result name="success">/WEB_INF/View/TestPage.jsp</result>
```

After search on web I found a plugin - struts convention plugin to achieve this, But it follows its Naming convention.

Can I override Struts convention plugin configuration (that will not follow its naming convention)?I have tried too, but it is not reflecting. My `struts.xml` is

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMoade" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/View/" />

    <package name="test" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="hello1" class="testAction.Hello1Action">
            <result name="success">/TestPage.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

When I run

```
localhost:8080/project-name/hello1
```

It displays error 404.But if I change result in struts.xml as

```
<result name="success">/WEB-INF/View/TestPage.jsp</result>
```

It works fine.

I don't wanna do changes in all result tags.How can I achieve this by doing changes at one place?

Comment: If you've read linked question why do you have wrong location set according to accepted answer in this question?

Comment: I have tried that too, but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention plugin uses a different configuration provider and this constant only works with configuration created by convention.

```xml
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/View/" />
```

If you want to override the convention configuration you should use annotations.

```java
package testAction;

@ParentPackage("json-default")
@Namespace("/")
@Action(value="hello1", results=@Result(name = "success", location="TestPage.jsp"))
public class Hello1Action extends ActionSupport {
}
```

Comment: Can't we use it through configuration file - struts.xml ?

Comment: The constant you write in `struts.xml`, the action configuration write in annotations. The action configuration from `struts.xml` remove.

Comment: Can't we use action configuration in struts.xml instead of annotations?

Comment: You can use action configuration, but it doesn't work with above constant.

Comment: Is It struts limitation Or something wrong with my configuration? If I wanna achieve this, how can i do that?

Comment: It's your mistake, you should understand and follow the said above.

Comment: *Can I override Struts convention plugin configuration (that will not follow its naming convention)?* Yes, use annotations. *I have tried too, but it is not reflecting.* Because you didn't remove the action configuration from `struts.xml`.

Comment: If you want to override the action configuration from `struts.xml` using convention plugin's annotations, no you can't. This is the answered here.

Comment: Thank you, This is I was looking for. Now I ll try to convenience my manager to use annotations ;)

Comment: If this answer helped you to understand and solve your problem, you should mark it as accepted solution.